# Trimming veneer across the grain

Tags: veneer

I am applying veneer to some bedroom furniture. I cut the veneer pieces so they overhang the substrate about 1 - .5 inches on all edges, and then I trim the veneer flush with the substrate.  This is going really well when I'm trimming the veneer with the grain.  But I have horrible tear out when I trim across the grain.  I tried a file and a knife with new blades.  But I still had issues.  Any suggestions?  Do I need a veneer saw for this?  Or should I just use a sanding block (which would be a bummer since the edges I'm worried about are 3 ft long -- that's a lot of sanding).  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you cutting "into"" the support or pushing the veneer off the support? I find cutting "into" works with a "very" sharp blade.

Comment: I find clamping a strip above the veneer helps reduce chipping, I did a birds maple piece and found that I had to steam the veneer or the knots would chip out before the lady bug steamer I used to use a damp towel and an iron. Make sure to give the piece time to dry after steaming prior to any finish coating.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that this be moved to [woodworking.se].

Comment: Re. a veneer saw, it's my understanding that these work best for trimming to width (i.e. cutting along the grain) which makes perfect sense since the teeth on them sure look like they're filed rip. And that actually the ideal way to cut across the grain **is** using a knife. Perhaps you just need to modify your technique with the knife.... can you describe how you're currently doing it? It might be worth mentioning also that not all blades are made equal, and utility knife blades may not be up to snuff. If that's the case with yours you could try honing & stropping them, but it's tricky to do.

Comment: [contd] But it is quite doable to exceed the sharpness of the factory edge with a bit of practice; an alternative is to switch knife type, e.g. use an X-acto or scalpel. Re. sanding, FWIW I know a lot of users who swear by it as **the** way to trim veneer (with the paper backed by a hard block) but obviously this is just to remove the last little bit. The major trimming is done prior to this, and AFAIK commonly with a knife or chisel edge (using the chisel as a knife is widely recommended in older writing, for this and other duties where now we generally use a marking knife or utility knife).

Comment: Use a straight edge and sharp utility knife to score the veneer. And you don't have to cut through it in one pass.